# How to log SQLite errors in react native

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, native

Im not able to save some data to a SQLite table, im pretty shure the error is somwehere in my query. 
I would like to log what its going wrong but im not able to log the error in the console.

Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong here?

```
insertLens(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO lenses (vendor, name) VALUES (?,?)',
            ['foo', 'bar']),
            (_, { result }) => {
                console.log(result._array);
            },
            (_, error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why dont you look at the device logs? `adb logcat`  and filter by your application for example?

Comment: That does not explain why the above code is not logging the error if it occures.

Comment: Do you know the plugin you're using successfully executes the Javascript call back?  If you looked in the device logs, you'll be able to see if there is an SQL error. If the plugin doesn't invoke the Callback, then the error will never show.